# Does PHP Laravel has a database schema file like Rails

Tags: php, laravel

I am a Rails developer and now oceanically works on PHP Laravel.
In Rails, schema.rb is a file that summarizes the database, which is very convenient for a developer to understand the database schema, for example, what the data type of a column is.

I'm wondering if Lavaral has the similar file as Ruby on Rails or any workaround for Lavaral developer? So far, I can only find the migration files to look at the data type, which is very inconvenient.

### This is a sample of the Rails schema file, does Php Laravel has the similar file:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130315230445) do

    create_table "microposts", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "content"
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
    end

    add_index "microposts", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id_and_created_at"

    create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "follower_id"
        t.integer  "followed_id"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
    end

    add_index "relationships", ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
    add_index "relationships", ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
    add_index "relationships", ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"

    create_table "users", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "email"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.string   "password_digest"
        t.string   "remember_token"
        t.boolean  "admin"
    end

    add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    add_index "users", ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token"

    end
```

Comment: There's no single file; the migrations files give you an overall record of it.

Comment: Take a look at Laravel Migration: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply, no - it doesn't have have a `schema.rb` file like Rails.